# SQL: create a recordset by repeating the output of one query for every record of a second query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, database-administration

I have a query that returns records as below

**vw_EmployeeReferenceNumbers**

```
NAME       Number
----       ------
AA         123
AA         234
AA         456
```

I have another table that returns records like so

**AllEmployees**

```
   AllNames
    ----------
    AA
    BB
    CC
```

I want to output a recordset like so

```
NAME       Number
----       ------
AA         123
AA         234
AA         456
BB         123
BB         234
BB         456
CC         123
CC         234
CC         456
```

I dont want to use Cursors at all. I cant modify the view vw_EmployeeReferenceNumbers or the table AllEmployees. Can this be done in SQL?

What I have so far that doesn't work is:

```
select name, number
from 
(select Name, number, 1 as id from vw_EmployeeReferenceNumbers
) as A
left join
(select name, 1 as id from AllEmployees
) as B
on A.id = B.id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `cross join`:

```
select e.name, ern.number
from AllEmployees e cross join
     vw_EmployeeReferenceNumbers ern;
```

Comment: THat didnt work. I just get AA repeating all the time.

Comment: @Gordon is correct based off the info you have given. [fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5faa1/1)

Comment: @user20358 . . . This will have all employees, although it might start with all the `AA`s.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT e.name, 
       ern.number
FROM AllEmployees e INNER JOIN
     EmployeeReferenceNumbers ern ON 1=1
ORDER BY e.name
```